# Android/Cocos2d-x - C++ Framework - Trying to test a CCFadeOutTRTiles

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I was trying to apply a CCFadeOutTRTiles effect in a Sprite but whole screen was affected. I need change pixelFormat in EAGLView but I don't know how change it. Someone could help me?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

I did an update to version 2 and it worked fine.
tks